# SQL raiserror output in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that for testing purposes always throws an error.

```
UPDATE [Test]
    SET  [1.1] = 0
        ,[1.2] = 0
        ,[1.3] = 0
        ,[1.4] = 0

    WHERE Record_ID = 2 AND
          [1.1] = 0 AND
          [1.2] = 0 AND
          [1.3] = 0 AND
          [1.4] = 0
if(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    begin 
    raiserror('Error on purpose',16,1)
END
```

While the error gets thrown in SQL MGMT studio, it does not get triggered in try/catch block in asp.net.

I call the SP like so:

```
try {
     dataContext.TESTProcedure();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    string error = ex.Message;
}
```

I have stepped through the code and it never enters the catch even though it should.

What is going wrong?

Comment: is @@rowcount = 0?  I would debug the stored procedure to make sure raiseerror is being encountered.

Comment: Trace SQL Profiler what query is being passed from code and try it in SSMS. As an alternative raise an error without IF condition.

Comment: Yes it triggers the error and rowcount is = 0. The error is raised in sql management studio

Answer (score 0):

I would go deeper into what dataContext is doing.  If behind the scenes it is using a datareader, then one may have to advance to the next result set to get the error.

Call

```
NextResult
```

on the reader.  For more information:

> "So how do we get this to work? Well, when using a SqlDataReader it
> will only iterate over the first result set, which in this case will
> be the select in the stored procedure. This result set will be empty
> since there is no data for ID number 10. So nothing is displayed and
> the second result set is not accessed. What we have to do is to move
> into the next result set in order to get hold of the error.
>
> One way to do this is to as follows, ie, this will keep going over all
> the returned result sets until the SqlDataReader is closed, which it
> will be when there are no more result sets returned."

Originally, this text was pulled from here:

```
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/04/06/catch-a-sql-server-raiserror-at-client-side-using-sqldatareader.aspx
```

This link is no longer available and will return a 403.  I am keeping it here as a source of reference for the original author.  Not sure where this information was moved.

Comment: Link is 403 now